# What does this webrtc warning mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc

I get the following warning when trying to establish a video+audio connection using native `webRTC` on `iOS7`.

> Warning(webrtcsession.cc:1423): Candidate has unknown component:
>   Cand[3902756006:2:udp:2122063615:192.168.178.26:59273:local::0::] for
>   content: audio

I get it a few times, some with audio at the end, some with video. I can currently establish a connection and receive audio on both ends. Video is sent (not 100% sure), but not quite received yet (the screen is rendered black).

My environment:

- Testing on an iPad3 and an iPad4
- Both run the latest iOS
- Developing using Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)
- I have my own signaling server, hosted on my LAN
- I'm using a turn server, hosted on my LAN (same device as the signaling server)
- My complete log from starting the app to getting audio on both ends can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/8dEzsiZt)

Comment: what is the full candidate object that causes this error?

Comment: @BenjaminTrent lines <811, 823, 828, 829, 834, 835, 838, 841> from the log I linked contain these warnings, they include the full ice candidate. These are all the candidates I have sent to the other peer, and the warning is generated when I try to addIceCandidate on my peerConnection object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These warnings have to do with calling WebRTC methods on different threads, while really all calls to the library need to be done on the same thread. I have had success with everything on a single background thread as well as everything on the main thread, aas long as it's the same one throughout the app's lifetime.